# Disable Internet access my router's UI

Tags: router, remote-access, wimax

[image]

My admin interface can be accessed by anyone on the Internet. This is a security risk.

That is, this remote management service is to be **disabled**.  So how can I disable this Remote access.  My router is **Pointmax2500**, and my connection is **Wi-max**.

**The above screenshot is the Internet security warning from avast**

avast is showing this **warning** even after unchecking ***allow connection from wan***

When I clicked on "Go to router settings" from avast, this webpage is displayed:

[image]

Pointmax page:

[image]

Comment: I did according to the answer from [http://superuser.com/users/315073/virtualdj].even then the same warning is displayed by avast.

Comment: What else can i do virtualdj ?

Comment: I **unchecked** allow connection from WAN.still the same **warning** is displayed by avast..I need help.

Comment: In my opinion disabling the checkbox is enough because you shouldn't be able to reach the router web interface from the Internet. If Avast is still complaining, maybe you can try changing the router password with a stronger one.

Comment: The same message may appear if you have some port-forwarding enabled (see [here](http://www.chennaishop.com/protect-your-router-from-hackers/)), but this is not harmful as Avast suggests if you've done it intentionally.

Comment: When i clicked on router settings from avast,this webpage is displayed.??

Comment: **Your connection is not private** message is due to Avast HTTPS scanning which is preventing you to access your router web interface (pretty fun as it's actually Avast that complains for configuring it correctly!).
So try to disable it as described [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/10/31/avasts-https-scanning-interferes-with-firefox-and-other-programs/): open Avast **dashboard**, click **Settings** > **Active protection** > **Customize** and **uncheck Enable HTTPS scanning**.

Answer (score 3):

You can **disable** the checkbox **Allow Connection from WAN** on the screenshot you've posted to disallow Internet users to access your router configuration web interface.

Comment: Please use Comments to get clarification from the OP, Answers should be answers, not another question. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Sorry, actually I didn't mean to ask for details. I edited my replay to make it an answer.

Comment: No problem, looks good now.